# How to login into symfony by URL

Tags: php, security, symfony, error-logging

I research on cookbook the chapter relative of security and the most near is the part **How to Authenticate Users with API Keys**. I'm not sure if is possible to login in synfony through URL. I try to develop a service that permit login and I want to use a URL like this:

> `mysite.com/login/user/password/token`

Before to make the complete code I try to make a test and be sure thats works and I pass my var with value in the same code in controller:

```
$_username="user";
$_password="password";

$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('subscriber_login_check'));

if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
    $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
} else {
    $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
}
```

When I try to do this on controller I have the follow error :

> Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check/". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

I don't know if I need to so something else in others files or this is not possible to do it.

Thank you

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure that's such a great way to do it. You'd be sending the password through GET which isn't recommended which is why it's probably hard finding examples. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671599/are-security-concerns-sending-a-password-using-a-get-request-over-https-valid

Comment: I stopped reading at synfony. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can find a solution to implement my login with URL like this: mysite.com/user/password.

This is the code:

```
$path_info = $request->getPathInfo();
$router_parts = explode("/", $path_info);
$routerAux = $router_parts[1];
$routerAux2 = $router_parts[2];
if ($routerAux != ""){
    $_username=$routerAux;
    $user = $em->getRepository('myBundle:Entity')->findOneBy(array('field' => $_username));
    if($user){
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), "public", $user->getRoles());
        if($token){
            if ($routerAux2  != ""){
                $_password=$routerAux2;
                $pass = $user->getPassword();
                $pass1 =""; 
                $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
                        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
                        $pass1 = $encoder->encodePassword($_password, $user->getSalt());
                if($pass==$pass1){
                    $var= 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }     
    }
    return $this->render('Bundle:Pages:page.html.twig',array('var'=>$var));
}
```

Basically, the service is implemented by sending the **username** and **password** by URL, and initially locate the **username** in my **database**, then if the user exists got the **password**. Because the **password is encrypted**, proceeded to encrypt the value of the past password URL. Once encrypted value that a comparison between the two values is performed to return true if both are equal and false if they are different.